# Why is this regex pattern from json schema not validated in swagger?

Tags: java, json, swagger, schema, jsonschema

I'm using json schema to validate the inputs of my Swagger definition using Open API 3.0. In Swagger editor, the validation works perfectly if I try to introduce string in a numeric field. However, I noticed that the pattern of the name property is not working because when I am inserting lowercase characters swagger thinks that it is a valid data, which is incorrect.

I noticed that I have the same problem if I use minLength to validate the length of the string. Also, the json schema is working fine because it validates correctly the json object if I use lowercase characters.

This is my Swagger Definition:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: '1.0.0'
  title: 'EXAMPLE1'
  description: 'Example API to test jsonschema'
  termsOfService: https://smasrtbear.com/terms-of-use
  contact:
    name: something
    url: smartbear.com
    email: aaa@asdad.net
  license:
    name: SmartBear License
    url: http://license.foo.com
servers:
  - url: https://dev.foo.com
    description: Dev Server
  - url: https://prod.foo.com
    description: Prod Server
paths: 
  /example:
    get:
      description: To get some information
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: query
          description: Some Id example
          schema:
            $ref: 'http://localhost:5555/mytest#/properties/id'
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: some name for example
          schema:
            $ref: 'http://localhost:5555/mytest#/properties/name'
        - name: price
          in: query
          description: some price for example
          schema:
            $ref: 'http://localhost:5555/mytest#/properties/price'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful example
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  properties:
                    id:
                      type: integer
                      example: 4
                    name:
                      type: string
                      example: John Smith
                    price:
                      type: integer
                      example: 114
```

Please noticed that I'm using #ref to connect to a remote json schema

This is the schema.

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "price"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "$id": "/properties/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Id Schema",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [
        1
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "$id": "/properties/name",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Name Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "A GREEN DOOR"
      ],
      "pattern": "^([A-Z]*)$"
    },
    "price": {
      "$id": "/properties/price",
      "type": "number",
      "title": "The Price Schema",
      "default": 12,
      "examples": [
        12
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This should be invalid in swagger.

{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "abcdefg",
    "price": 114
  }

Would be a problem with OpenApi3.0?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "not validated in Swagger"? Swagger is not a single tool but a collective name for several tools - Swagger UI, Swagger Codegen, and others. Do you mean input validation in Swagger UI when you do "try it out"? Or do you mean server-side validation of request data in the server code generated by Swagger Codegen? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched form SwaggerEditor to SwaggerHub.